# problem with like

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

```
 preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select fname,lname, "
                + "sportman_code
                + "from sportman,customer "
                + "where customer.customer_code = "
                + "sportman.customer_code and  fname like ? ");
         String s = jTextField1.getText();
         if(s.length() == 0)
             s = String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar());

         s = "'%" + s;
         s += "%'" ;
         System.out.println(s);

         preparedStatement.setString(1, s);
         resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

When I write  `when(resultset.next)` didn't enter into while loop.

For example there is lisa in `fname` but when I enter `l` didn't enter into while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where are the closing double quotes in this line

   + "sportman_code
2. You dont need to quote the pattern that will do preparedStatement.setString() for you.

   s = "%" + s + "%";

Answer (score 0):

try without single quotes

```
s= "%" +s + "%"
```